# How to dynamically update a viewset in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I think I am just putting this code in the wrong place but was wondering if someone could help out here.  I wanted to get an item from the db for the last business day.  This works fine, but it seems the below gets compiled when i start the app with gunicorn.  So now the current_b_day is evaluated as 11/13 (today = 11/16).  But this never changes.  So my viewset will always return the same dataset even though i am adding new data to the db via an alternate process.  If i bring the server down and back up, it will recompile and get a new value for current_b_day.  Any help is much appreciated!

**views.py**

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay, BMonthEnd, BYearEnd
from datetime import date, datetime

    class YieldCurveViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        current = date.today()
        current_b_day = current - BDay(1)  #This never changes and is compiled in!
    
        queryset = YieldCurve.objects.filter(create_date=current_b_day)
        serializer_class = YieldCurveSerializer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Django Rest Framework documentation](http://www.cdrf.co/3.1/rest_framework.viewsets/ModelViewSet.html#get_queryset) the queryset you're using is evaluated only once.
To force re-evaluation for each request you should implement the `get_queryset` method in the `ViewSet`.

For a simple filter where your model has a Foreign Key User:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return YieldCurve.objects.filter(user = self.request.user)
```

Or in your case:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    current = date.today()
    current_b_day = current - BDay(1)    
    return YieldCurve.objects.filter(create_date=current_b_day)
```

Hope this works!

Edit: if it doesn't work, copy the function from the linked page and add your functionality. I provided code that works in our codebase, so I left the extra functions out.

Comment: Thanks!  I knew the answer was in the documentation I just couldn't think of what to search for.  I am running it through debug and can see it is being evaluated everytime I hit the URL.  Thanks again!